# Calling a procedure in a DLL passing String-like parameters

Tags: delphi, dll, parameters, call, procedure

I have a DLL that has a Form.
I have an application that calls this DLL.
I'm trying to put a Caption in the Form inside the DLL through the  Application's call.

Here is how the DLL creates the Form:

```
procedure CallEmployee(Title: PWideChar); export; stdcall;
begin
   Frm_Standard := TFrm_Standard.Create(nil,DA,[],[]); //I have a modified Constructor
   Frm_Standard.Caption := Title;
```

This is the declaration of the DLL's procedure in the Application:

```
procedure CallEmployee(Title: PWideChar); external 'Employee.dll';
```

And this is how I'm making the call right now:

```
//I wanna put a title according to an specific test (Not this one, obviously)
if 2 = 2 then 
  CallEmployee(PWideChar('This Title'));
```

I'm using PWideChar because I found out that String doesn't work in this situation.

It must be something small that I'm missing, but I researched and I just couldn't find a solution.

I find a few things for Functions, but since I don't need to return any parameters, I'm using a simple procedure. Or that might be the root of my problems, to begin with?

I'm using Delphi XE7.

And sorry if this question is irrelevant or has already been asked, but I couldn't find it. If it already has an answer, just tell me and I'll delete this question.

Ah, everything else works perfectly, the procedure calls the Form, it is shown correctly, but the title always comes out like this:

[Weird Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJQj.jpg)

Comment: An aside, the `export` directive is ignored, you should remove it so that you don't think it actually means anything!

Comment: you forgot `stdcall;` on the caller declaration

Comment: Also consider using BPL instead of DLL - that way you would be both able to pass strings as is and be safe from such simple to make hard to find an error, because the compiler would check the correctness fo all the datatypes including function declaration

Comment: BPLs are usually pointless at runtime. You'd usually compile the code into one module, if you controlled it all.  Multiple modules are useful when you want to support mutiple hosts. At which point BPLs are no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the calling convention. Replace:

```
procedure CallEmployee(Title: PWideChar); external 'Employee.dll';
```

with

```
procedure CallEmployee(Title: PWideChar); stdcall; external 'Employee.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that almost solved my problem. I tried your suggestion, but that'd give me an access violation, then I tried changing the type of variable (for Integer) and it worked. Long story short, your answer works for Integer, but not for PWideChar. That aside, thanks a lot, it was helpful :)

Comment: No. My answer is correct and complete. Your access violation is due to other code that we can't see.

Comment: Or your code isn't as you've shown here. Note that you have a parameter named Titulo but you then refer to something named Title. So perhaps that's related to the issue. All the same, the only problem with the interop, as presented, is the calling convention.

Comment: I was translating my code to english, but I forgot that part. I'll change that. I'll try to post here the error and where it occurs.

Comment: That is just great. I tried like 5~6 times, and the error would occur always in the same line, the same message. I tried it now and it worked. I give up. Anyways, thanks for the answer, I'll use PWideChar. String usage in this case is a bad practice or it might not work in some cases? Or none of the previous?

Comment: String is a private delphi type. Can only be used reliably if the same compiler is used on both sides, and a shared MM is used. True interop types are usually preferable.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot, mate. Have a nice day.